# Why ON earth is stackoverflow more strict than the other sites?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, spam, posting

On stack overflow, it is much easier to see the

> You post cannot be submitted due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network

error. Also this you can only post every 90 minutes thing is more strongly enforced on there. I post something on A DIFFERENT SITE and then I switch accounts and then I try to post on Stack Overflow, and it says you can only post every 90 minutes, then I go to another site an my question is submitted no problem. It seems for some reason that posting restrictions are applied more harshly there than on other sites. Why? My question is COMPLETELY different because I am asking why stackoverflow is more strict then other sites.

Comment: I think these are two unrelated incidents. The former issue you've quoted is IP-based AFAIK, and you can't really help it unless you use "contact us" at the bottom of the page. Are you sure the second issue is not just because where you went to other site it was already 90 minutes?

Comment: @M.A.R. It have not been 90 minutes when I switched sites.

Comment: @M.A.R. I doubt the IP based block due to SPAM can be lifted, so using the contact us form is probably of no use.

Comment: Other than that, it would be natural for SO to be stricter because of the sheer number of users (which is correlated with the number of *ab*users).

Comment: Do you mean with *different site* a site within the SE network of sites? And that *other site* you mention is also in the SE network?

Comment: Switch accounts on SE?  Yeah, that's a common process for spam networks.  I suspect that's what's triggering the spam blockage.  Why are you using different accounts, and what are the other one(s)?

Comment: SO is different than *what* other sites? The rest of the SE network?  It's not.

Comment: I wish someone would explain why it could be necessary to post to SO with a higher frequency than one per 90, (other than spam, lists of homework questions, SO-centric development and other abuses)?  Many have complained about that rate limit and I don't understand why.

Comment: @MartinJames It takes me an 45 minutes to an hour alone to write a question, and then there's the time required to actually do debugging and research before asking. I suspect that's common for people familiar with the site. I can't ever see the 90 minute restriction being a problem for someone using the site correctly.

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow (and all other sites in the SE network) are more strict because the goal of all these sites is to build up a collection of valuable knowledge for future visitors to read and learn from.

For that reason the quality standards on the sites are rather high and content or behavior that is deemed not to be a good fit for that goal is moderated fiercely by the members of the community once they earned the privilege to do so. So far the balance is that a few blocked users doesn't hamper the overall content quality, so the bans and throttles work.

The Stack Exchange team developed a wide range of techniques, data collection and matching strategies to either ban or throttle the admission of content that originates from certain IP-addresses or even IP-ranges. For low reputation accounts these throttles are a bit more tightened. Once an account gains more reputation the throttle is adapted as well until it is hardly noticeable.

Some of the throttling / banning is done at the edge of the physical computer network of Stack Exchange which lead to the blocking of traffic from certain IP addresses across the whole SE computer network. Other throttling is done at network account level and some at user level, which is per site.

Even under normal operation actions from users are rate limited as is explained in [The complete rate-limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

So why on earth is Stack Overflow more strict than other sites? Because we care deeply about the content found here and that is best preserved to slow down those users and/or computer network that submits sub-par content, allowing them to spend more time reading and learning the ropes of contributing on the Q/A sites in the SE network, instead of letting them go and the community have to clean-up afterwards.